# Python not writing value to a file

Tags: python

I have following html:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Please enter domain to add to EDL.</p>
<form action="/cgi-bin/domain.py" method="post">
Domain:  <input type="text" name="domain"></br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Import modules for CGI handling
import cgi, cgitb

# Create instance of FieldStorage
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# Get data from fields
domain2 = form.getvalue('domain')

with  open('/tmp/pa-allowed-credentials.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(domain2)


print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2>%s added to the list</h2>" % (domain2)
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

The problem I'm having is the python script is not writing the value of "domain2" into the file.  If i execute the script via "python domain.py" it works correctly.

Comment: You don't need `f.close()` in the `with` block. It will automatically be closed when you exit the `with` block.

Comment: The value of domain2 from `print "<h2>%s added to the list</h2>" % (domain2)` shows in the browser?

Comment: Removing f.close() from the with statement made no difference.  Still not writing to the file.

Comment: @Pawamoy - its helpful to note that this is a side note and not an explanation of the bug. OP had to go test and find out it didn't fix the bug.

Comment: @tdelaney yes, the value of domain2 shows in the browser.

Comment: That ruins my theory! I guess its possible that your web server is picking up an old version of the script. But _really_ guessing there.

Comment: My theory was that your web server was a different user and didn't have rights to append after you created the file as you. (the test is to just delete the file). But since the open didn't stack trace, that's not it.

Comment: @tdelaney restarted httpd service, no go.

Comment: You could gather some info such as original content of the file and then return value from `f.write` then add them to the output page. At least you'd have some debug info.

Comment: @tdelaney, yes new user, should have added that note. When we're lost we always change the code byte after byte to see if the ouptut changes though, even for things that seem unrelated to the bug. So I guess it's not bad for the OP to do as well.